# C# - Int operation inexplicably returning negative value

Tags: c#, floating-point, int

Operation is as follows:

```
public float InfectionPercent()
{
    return (infected + zombies) * 100 / population;
}
```

the values are:

```
int infected = 20196093
int zombies = 1978138
int population = 32608521
```

The value returned is `-63`

Changing `100` to `100f` fixes this.

---

Why is that operation returning `-63` instead of `63`?

Comment: what are infected, zombies, population types? short? int?

Comment: @LoganMurphy ops forgot! They're all `int`s

Comment: Possibly .Net is smart enough to understand that there is no zombies around

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
20196093 + 1978138 = 22174231
22174231 * 100 = 2 217 423 100
```

However, Int.MaxValue is `2 147 483 647`, so you're busting the max value.

By setting `100` as a `float` you are forcing a float multiplication. Valid `float` values are be between `-3.4 × 10^38` and `+3.4 × 10^38` (which is 340 undecillion, i.e. quite a lot) so it is indeed correct.

Comment: And a float isn't bound by the same max value? Or is something else going on with floats?

Comment: why not setting all of them to long?

Comment: @kul_mi I will now :)

Comment: @RadiantHex Float range goes from `-3.4 × 10^38` to `+3.4 × 10^38` so no, it's totally not the same max value.

Comment: Actually, the `float` range is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `float` have the constants `infinity`, but cannot contain an infinite number, it stops at `3.4 x 10^38`. If you need to store a bigger number, there's double that goes up to `1.7 × 10^308`. I mean, for example it is impossible that a computer can contain the number 1 followed by 100 billion billions other 1 in a register, that would just be silly.. It cannot be infinite since the storage space is finite.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Not true, as Pierre-Luc points out, it only has special constants to _represent_ infinity. If you were to write `(float.MaxValue == float.MaxValue + 1)` it would evaluate as `true`.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: You may store infinity in a floating-point object, and it will display as infinity when formatted for output and will act as infinity in arithmetic. The [Microsoft Documentation] says that their `Single` type can represent infinity.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: `float.MaxValue +1` evaluates to `float.MaxValue` because of rounding. Try `float.MaxValue*float.MaxValue`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: `float.IsInfinity(float.MaxValue*float.MaxValue) == true` Point is, `float` does not represent any values properly beyond 3.402823e38. (you're right though, my example was _too_ contrived). `float` can _represent_ infinity, but it is incorrect to state that its _range_ is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: A correct statement is that `float` does not represent any finite values beyond about 3.4e38. It certainly does represent another value beyond that point: Infinity is properly represented. The actual range is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Stating that the _range_ is "–∞ _to_ +∞" indicates that it represents all values between the two. This is not the case. The accurate way to describe the range for `float` is [single-precision 32-bit numbers with values ranging from negative 3.402823e38 to positive 3.402823e38, as well as positive or negative zero, PositiveInfinity, NegativeInfinity, and not a number (NaN).](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.aspx) (notice that the only _"to"_ range indicated is -3.402823e38 to 3.402823e38, not _to_ infinity)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Does stating the range is from -3.402823e38 to 3.402823e38 indicate that `float` represents all values between the two? `float` does not represent all values in that range. There is a huge gap, 2**104, between `float.MaxValue` and the next lower representable value. You can fit ten thousand universes in that many meters. There is a gap between **every** pair of representable values in `float`. So gaps do not terminate the range. The range is simply the interval from the smallest representable value to the largest representable value, which is –∞ to +∞.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You can't indeed represent all values between the two. That's why float precision is 7 decimals. And you can't represent every numbers to infinity, that's why the range stops at 3.4e38

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault: If the fact that you cannot represent every number up to infinity is why the range stops at the previous value, then why does not the fact that you cannot represent every number up to about 3.4e38 mean that the range stops at the previous value? Would you please show me any two different points, x and y, such that every number between x and y is representable as a `float`?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair A `float` can't even represent all numbers between `1f` and `2f`. For example the mathematical number **1.2** (six fifths) is unrepresentable. But the range is still from `NegativeInfinity` to `PositiveInfinity`. Being a 32-bit fixed width type, it can never represent more than 4,294,967,296 distinct values. There have to be "holes" between the values.

Comment: I meant that it can represent values between +-MaxValue within the bounds of its 32bit single-precision rules. To me, describing the range of `float` to be "-infinity to +infinity" is inaccurate as you can't describe values like 1x10^200 with it.

Answer (score 3):

This is an integer overflow error

`2,147,483,647` is the max c# integer value

`20,196,093 + 1,978,138 = 22,174,231`

`22,174,231 * 100 = 22,174,231 * 100 = 2,217,423,100`

(integer overflows to `-2,077,544,195`)

`-2,077,544,195 / 32,608,521 = -63.71169655318007`

Converting to float prevents this issue because float does not overflow for a long time and when it does it ends up being infinite.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to the problem would be to forcing a float multiplication like you did by using `100f` (for reasons explained by Pierre-Luc Pineault). However, if you want a whole number result returned without casting explicitly, make your variables `uint` as they can only be positive.

```
uint infected = 20196093
uint zombies = 1978138
uint population = 32608521

public uint InfectionPercent()
{
    return (infected + zombies) * 100 / population;
}

//output is 68 (float output is 68.00134)
```

Might not be a bottleneck but if it's a realtime game, you'll likely get better performance because you're avoiding the casting of `int` to `float` (of course, that might be a micro-optimization depending on how often you call it).

Edit - As Chris correctly mentioned in the comments, it'd better to use `long` instead of `uint` in this case.

Comment: I'd recommend using `long` (or `ulong`) instead of `uint`. `uint` will only double the cap at which the overflow is hit which is still very plausible to have.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair - +1 That's a good point. Haven't used `long` in a while and it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

max number an integer can hold is 2,147,483,647. If your variables infected and zombies are both integers, they exceed this number because {(infected + zombies) * 100} = 2,217,423,100 > 2,147,483,647. Because it maxes out the integer number, is goes into negatives. Try to make the infected and zombies variables into floats or force a float multiplication by making 100 into 100.00.

Comment: The maximum value an `int` can have may be 2,147,483,647, but there are certainly larger integers. “Integer” does not mean `int`.